# Are the request limits in BITS/BYTES?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

There are 2 sections in the asp.net web.config and im looking for a definitive word on what they actually represent (bits or bytes). The first:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
   <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="?" />
   </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

And the second:

```
<system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="?" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

The '?''s show the values that I just dont understand if they are speaking about bits or bytes.

Any advice and supporting artciles :-) would be really helpful.

Pete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to MSDN:

> [HttpRuntimeSection.MaxRequestLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx)

-says kilobytes

> [requestLimits Element for requestFiltering [IIS 7 Settings Schema]](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits)

-says bytes

Comment: maybe google didnt have an SO page with the answer already =)

Answer (score 1):

[`maxRequestLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx): The maximum request size in kilobytes. The default size is 4096 KB (4 MB).

[`maxAllowedContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28VS.90%29.aspx):
Specifies the maximum length of content in a request, in bytes. The default value is 30000000.